# What does 「アップしています」 mean?

Tags: loanwords

For example:

> Youtubeで動画をアップしています。

Does 「アップ」 mean “upload”?

Comment: You can also say it ようつべで動画をうｐしています。　:D

Answer (score 6):

As you guessed, アップ is short for アップロード meaning upload. Adding する makes it into a verb. ～ている has a lot of uses so I will just say without any further context 「YOUTUBEで動画をアップしています」 could be 'I upload videos on youtube' (repeated action), 'I have videos/the video uploaded on youtube' (resultant state) or 'I am uploading a video on youtube' (continuous).

Answer (score 4):

アップする is a 和製英語/abbreviation meaning "to upload".